# Timeout observable subscription without value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire

I'm subscribing to an observable returning values from Firebase. If something is off with the connection I want the subscription to time out. What is the correct way of doing this? I tried the following but this is timing out 20 seconds after I received the last value:

```
let chatSubscription = this.getChats().timeoutWith(20000, Observable.throw(new Error('timeout'))).subscribe(chats => { ... });
```

//edit: getChats()

```
getChats() {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            let chatList = this.db.list('/users/' + this.auth.user.uid + '/chats').timeoutWith(20000, Observable.throw(new Error('timeout'))).subscribe(chats => {
                observer.next(chats);
            });  
            //keep track of this subscription
            this.openSubscriptions.push(chatList);  
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you post your getChats() method

Comment: sure, should have done that before

Comment: do you need the Observable.create() wrapper? Can you just return the this.db.list(...) observable, then subscribe to it in your component?

Comment: It's not clear what is wrong with your current code. You said yourself, it times out after the last value. So what is the desired behavior?

Comment: I omitted some code to make it clear, which made it worse :) added again now. @Tamas, I want to timeout when I haven't received a single value after 20s.

Comment: I believe what is happening is the inner timeoutWith is firing, but you are not catching the error within your subscribe. try catching it and propagating it to the outer observable. `.subscribe(chats => {observer.next(chats)}, err => {observer.error(err)})` I guess the same goes for your outer observable, you'll need to catch the error in either a .catch() method or in the error callback of the .subscribe()

Comment: In fact the timeout is showing, but I don't want it to be there. Only when I don't receive any value within 20 seconds after subscribing I want to timeout, otherwise I want to keep the subscription open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `race` to listen to whichever observable first produces something:

```
const chats = this.db.list('/users/' + this.auth.user.uid + '/chats');
const timeout = Observable.throw(new Error("timed out")).delay(20000);
const chatWithTimeout = Observable.race(chats, timeout);
chatWithTimeout.subscribe(msg => ..., err => ...);
```

Also, your usage of `Observable.create` seems a bit unorthodox.  I'd suggest taking the above code and just using it as your `getChats`:

```
getChats() {
    const chats = this.db.list('/users/' + this.auth.user.uid + '/chats');
    const timeout = Observable.throw(new Error("timed out")) .delay(20000);
    const chatWithTimeout = Observable.race(chats, timeout);
    return chatWithTimeout;
}

// usage
const subscription = foo.getChats().subscribe(...);
```

With this version there's no need for you to keep a list of open subscriptions.  Let the observer keep track of this subscription themselves.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, thanks! One suggestion for improvement: delay doesn't directly work on 'throw', as it's only delaying onNext and onComplete calls (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/648):
const timeout = Observable.throw(new Error("timed out")).materialize(). .delay(20000).dematerialize();

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a timeout `Observable` and [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) from that initial timeout to your original values upon the first emitted item, like:

```
const chats$ = this.getChats();
chats$.map(v => Observable.just(v))
      .startWith(Observable.never().timeoutWith(20000, new Error()))
      .switchMap(v => v)
      .subscribe(...);
```

If a value is emitted within 20s of initialization, `switchMap` is just the identity operator and keeps supplying the items from the original value stream.